# Switching between list Fragment and new Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble figuring getting my head around switching a List Fragment and a new fragment.

My explanatory skills are not very good, but hopefully this crude image will give an idea of what im trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8gAs.jpg

When trying to change out my ListFragment to my new fragment I get the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

this is the output in logcat.

```
05-06 03:01:28.740    2578-2578/sqlite.testing.sqlitetest2.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sqlite.testing.sqlitetest2.app, PID: 2578
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:452)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My List Fragment is as follows

```
public class StaticCategoryFragment extends ListFragment {

StaticCategoryDataSource dataSource;
ArrayList<StaticCategory> categories;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    dataSource = new StaticCategoryDataSource(getActivity());

    try {

        dataSource.open();

        categories = dataSource.getAllCategorys();
        ArrayAdapter<StaticCategory> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<StaticCategory>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        dataSource.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    StaticCategory clickedCategory = categories.get(position);
    int categoryID = clickedCategory.getId();


    Fragment contentFrag = new BlankFragmentC();

    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("categoryID", categoryID);

    contentFrag.setArguments(data);

    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.list, contentFrag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

and the xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sqlite.testing.sqlitetest2.app.StaticCategoryFragment">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

I was wondering if some one could point out what I am doing wrong, and maybe point me in the direction of some documentation to get a better understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add code where your exception occurs. It looks like you try to call addView(View) method of listView. It's not possible, all adapterView in android unsupport adding view directly, Only via adapter. I think problem inside BlankFragmentC

Comment: You can add the whole fragment into `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to replace ListView with a new fragment. This is the issue

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.list, contentFrag);
```

What you could do:

1) Add to you .xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sqlite.testing.sqlitetest2.app.StaticCategoryFragment">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and then use:

```
ft.replace(R.id.container, contentFrag);
```

2) The best solution
Create activity and switch 2 fragments in this activity.
I.e. show in activity %list_fragment%. On list item click "send message" to activity telling that you want to switch fragments (using callbacks), and then switch fragments in activity

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Krossovochkin, Blackbelt, and GrlsHu for the help, you've helped me understand what I was doing wrong a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

the line causing the problem is

> ft.replace(android.R.id.list, contentFrag);

you should provide as `id`, the first parameter of `replace`, the id of the container where the `Activity` hosts the `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Fragments always needs some layout to load. You can not load fragment into View. You need any layout for that. You can use `FrameLayout` to load your fragment. In your code you are trying to load your fragment into `ListView` which not possible.

`ListView` always need adapter class which can bind a data into it. Whereas you are trying to load whole `Fragment` into it.

Either create one Adapter class to bind data into `ListView` or you load `Fragment` which contains a `ListView` inside it and bind data in that fragment only.